# Disable Prev Control on first slide and disable Next control on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

using Slick and looking for a way to have the prev control disabled and hidden until the user clicks the next arrow. Similarly I want the Next control to become disabled and hidden once the user reaches the last slide.

A good illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish is [here](http://www.asla.org/sustainablelandscapes/index.html)

Does slick have an attribute already for this that I have overlooked? Is this something that maybe can be accomplished using CSS by adding a disabled class?

The only thing similar I have found is this

```
$('.pages .slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    infinite: false,
    onAfterChange: function(slide, index) {
        if(index == 4){
        $('.pages .slider').slickPause();
```

But its not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Solution

You can add the css `pointer-events: none` to your button. That css property disable all event on an element. So something like that.

```
// Slick stuff
   ...
   onAfterChange: function(slide, index) {
       if(index === 4) {
           $('.slick-next').css('pointer-events', 'none')
       }
       else {
           $('.slick-next').css('pointer-events', 'all')
       }
   }
```

And something on the same guideline for `.slick-prev` element.

In that solution you should get the *function out of the config* and only put a reference to it with something like this.

```
// Inside slick config
onAfterChange: afterChange

// Below somewhere
var afterChange = function(slide, index) { //stuff here }
```

Also check to see if there is a way to get the length of the slider and verify it instead of hardcoding `4` in the `if` statement. You can probably do something like `$('.slide').length`

---

#### Edit

Here's how to implement the `afterChange()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scrollable').slick({
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        swipe: true,
        arrows: true,
        infinite: false,
     });

     $('.scrollable').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
    
        if(currentSlide === 2) {
            $('.slick-next').addClass('hidden');
        }
        else {
            $('.slick-next').removeClass('hidden');
        }

        if(currentSlide === 0) {
            $('.slick-prev').addClass('hidden');
        }
        else {
            $('.slick-prev').removeClass('hidden');
        }  
    })
});
```

And some CSS, If you wanna do animation you should do it here.

```
.slick-prev.hidden,
.slick-next.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: this is so very close, when I implement this solution however my slider breaks out of its container. There are 3 slides each slide has 3 rows of 5. 
Here is a fiddle to illustrate
http://jsfiddle.net/gward90/b25jgyox/4/

Comment: I added an edit on how to implement the after change function, I couldn't edit the fiddle for some reasons.

Comment: The same issue of the slider breaking is happening @Raphael Parent

Comment: Can you make the fiddle work like before. I'll try and make it work from that.

Comment: thanks http://jsfiddle.net/gward90/b25jgyox/8/

Make sure the fiddle run window is greater than 768px the arrows will only show up there.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer with the right code. I have problem with JSFiddle so I can't update your fiddle I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you very much, this gives me plenty to work from I will customize as necessary.

Comment: Next time, give a little more research in the documentation of what you are using. There was no `onAfterChange` property but it was an event. It could have saved us both time but I'm happy I could help :)

Answer (score 36):

Just use infite: false and create a custom css for class slick-disabled. Eg.

**JS - jQuery**

```
$('.my-slider').slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

**CSS**

```
.slick-disabled {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: is it true that in ie10 pointer-events:none; doesn't work? So in this old browser how could I disable effectively the arrow?

Comment: This was a very easy solution to implement. Thanks!

Comment: This is the best and easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple solution is:

1. set the infinite to false. eg

   ```
   $('.my-slider').slick({
    infinite: false });
   ```
2. add the following css

   `.slick-disabled {
     display: none; 
     pointer-events:none;
   }`

and that is it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple Way to style the Prev-/Next-Buttons if the first or last Item is reached. Make shure that the Infinite Mode is set to false. Then style the Buttons like this:

```html
.slick-arrow[aria-disabled="true"]{
 opacity: .5;
}
```

That's all you need!

Answer (score 2):

Add CSS code:

```
.slick-disabled {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very Simple Solution in Slick Slider Settings

```
$('.my-slider').slick({
     infinite: false 
});
```

Above settings will disable PREV and NEXT Arrows. But for hiding disabled arrows you need below CSS:

```
.slick-disabled {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: love that solution

Answer (score 1):

I modified the behavior of slick.js directly, like so:

```
// making the prevArrow not show on init:
if (_.options.infinite !== true) {
    _.$prevArrow
    .addClass('slick-disabled')
    .attr('aria-disabled', 'true')
    .css('display', 'none'); // The new line of code!
}
```

And:

```
if (_.options.arrows === true &&
    _.slideCount > _.options.slidesToShow &&
    !_.options.infinite
) {
    _.$prevArrow.removeClass('slick-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', 'false').css('display', '');
    _.$nextArrow.removeClass('slick-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', 'false').css('display', '');

    if (_.currentSlide === 0) {
        _.$prevArrow.addClass('slick-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', 'true').css('display', 'none');
        _.$nextArrow.removeClass('slick-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', 'false').css('display', '');
    } else if (_.currentSlide >= _.slideCount - _.options.slidesToShow && _.options.centerMode === false) {
        _.$nextArrow.addClass('slick-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', 'true').css('display', 'none');
        _.$prevArrow.removeClass('slick-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', 'false').css('display', '');
    } else if (_.currentSlide >= _.slideCount - 1 && _.options.centerMode === true) {
        _.$nextArrow.addClass('slick-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', 'true').css('display', 'none');
        _.$prevArrow.removeClass('slick-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', 'false').css('display', '');
    }
}
```

Just a matter of using the jquery `.css()` method and setting `display`. Seems to work quite dandily.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it is to slide to the same slide when you swipe(previous) on the first slide or swipe(next) on the last slide. Use swiper method swiper.SlideTo(n,n,m);

Comment: Yes, that is the other way to do it, but it's not what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

Put

```
 arrows: false,
```

in setting JSON config.
So simple!!

Answer (score 0):

For react and custom arrow.

```
const NxtArrow = ({ className, style, onClick }: any) => (
<div className={'slick-arrows2 slick-next2'} onClick={onClick}>
  <img
    style={{
      filter: onClick === null ? 'grayscale(100%)' : 'none',
      cursor: onClick === null ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer',
    }}
    className='sliderArrowsCustom'
    src={rightArrow}
    alt='leftarrow'
  />
</div> );

  const PrvArrow = ({ className, style, onClick }: any) => (
<div className={'slick-arrows2 slick-prev2'} onClick={onClick}>
  <img
    style={{
      filter: onClick === null ? 'grayscale(100%)' : 'none',
      cursor: onClick === null ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer',
    }}
    className='sliderArrowsCustom'
    src={leftArrow}
    alt='leftarrow'
  />
</div>  );

const settings = {
infinite: false,
nextArrow: <NxtArrow />,
prevArrow: <PrvArrow />,
}
```